# Using netbeans digitalclock sample

Tags: javafx, netbeans-8

I am a Java beginner with a question about the operation of the Digitalclock.java example in Netbeans 8.0.2

I want to alter the display to show only Hours and Minutes and change the color. I have found within the code a way to eliminate the display of the Seconds digits and change the color. What I can't do is get rid of the ":" or center the display.

1) Where is the ":" being generated from?
2) How would I center the display?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colon ":" in this case is not an actual character rather it is being generated by using multiple instances of the java circle class and can be found in line 114 - 117 of the DigitalClock.java file. Centering the the new four digit clock can be accomplished by changing the clock.setLayoutX at line 78. –  Six just now   edit